# Typing for a getValues + map operation

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to make TypeScript Typings that describe a mapping operation over a "Dictionary" / Object:

Given I have the following object:

```
let object = {
  a: "Hello",
  b: 1
}
```

I pass it though a method that takes each of the key value pairs and wrap it in a type of `Wrapped<T>`:

```
let newObject = Wrap(object);
```

So the best way I can describe it, is that I want newObject to have the equivalent type of:

```
interface NewObject {
    a: Wrapped<string>,
    b: Wrapped<number>
}
```

I have tried different approaches but I always end up with either a `any` type or type with `a` and `b` of type `Wrapped<unknown>`

Do anyone know if it is possible to describe this operation? Or if it impossible in TypeScript?

Comment: You can have a look here, they are called mapped types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types . Let me know, if you need additional help to define them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an interface in combination with `in keyof` like this (called [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types))

```js
type WrappedObject<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Wrapped<T[K]>;
}
```

With a fully working example:

```js
const object = {
    a: "Hello",
    b: 1
};

type Wrapped<T> = { value: T };
const _wrap = <T>(value: T) => ({ value });


type WrappedObject<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Wrapped<T[K]>;
}

const Wrap = <T extends Object>(obj: T): WrappedObject<T> => {

    const builder: Partial<WrappedObject<T>> = {};

    for (const k in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            builder[k] = _wrap(obj[k]);
        }
    }

    return builder as WrappedObject<T>;
};

let newObject = Wrap(object);
console.log(newObject.a.value);
```

Comment: Thank you - works like a charm  - TypeScript's Type System is awesome.